# Data structure for number wall

Tags: data-structures

I'm wondering what a good data structure for a number wall would be. Two neighbors sum up to give the number above them. Have all ok at the attached picture please

[image].

First, I would say it is a graph because one part is involved in to terms. But it might be to complecated to search through. A second idea would be to use a tree with doubling one leaf/node.

At the end, I need to fill the wall bottom up and apply certain shadow masks (patterns) to unfill nodes and leafes. So at the end, I need to find direct neighbors and their parents for the filling procedure.

What do you think?

Comment: A good structure depends on how you want to use it. You need to define some common operations you want, then decide what data structure you need to use.

Comment: Thanks @XiaotianPei. I have added some notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I suggest a vector of vectors?
i.e. a vector of elements such that the element at index `i` is itself a vector of size `i`.

Given that there will be `n` numbers in the bottom row of the wall,

## Creation

- Create a vector `V` of `n` elements, where the element at index `i` is itself a vector of size `i`
- Assign each index in the bottom-row vector (`V[n-1][0]` to `V[n-1][n-1]`) with your starting elements
- The value of each element `j` in a given row `i` can be calculated with a simple formula:

  ```
  V[i][j] = V[i+1][j] + V[i+1][j+1]
  ```
- This allows you to fill the rest of the structure (starting from the second-to-bottom row going up to the top) using two for-loops:

  ```
  for (i = size(V)-2; i >= 0; i--) // starting with the second-to-bottom row
      for (j = 0; j < size(V[i]); j++)
          V[i][j] = V[i+1][j] + V[i+1][j+1]
  ```

## Update

The for-loops above can be understood as an update step of the data structure, to be run whenever the bottom-row elements change.

## Extension

This structure is extensible by simply adding a vector of size `n+1` as a new row `V[n+1]` and then performing the update step.

## Access

Given any element `V[i][j]`,

- it has exactly 2 children `V[i+1][j]` and `V[i+1][j+1]` (unless it is in the bottom row of course)
- it has at least 1 (except the top element) and up to 2 parents

  - `V[i-1][j]`
  - `V[i-1][j-1]`

Comment: I missed that simple solution in my considerations. Thanks for that!